# how to center a web part in the center of sreen/web part zone

Tags: web-part, search-box, style.css

This has been asked before, yet I can't seem to get it to work.  As depicted in this image, my Search Box won't center align in the Web Part or page.  I tried several things... This is the latest:

```
#SearchBox { width: 650px; 
 margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 0px; border-spacing:10px 10px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below **CSS** style in `Script Editor Web Part`

```
<style>
   #SearchBox {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-right: -50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
</style>
```

**Or**

```
<style>
#SearchBox {
margin-left: 50% !important;
</style>
```

> **Note**: In the second style, you will need to Increase or decrease percent manually based on your requirements.

**Output**

[image]